# JQueryUI Autocomplete taking C# array, returns each character rather than each element

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm using a multiple autocomplete JQueryUI widget and I cannot for the life of me get the correct input.  I have an array defined in C# outside of the script that I am trying to use as the things to pull into the list, but it's always making each individual character in the array an element in the list rather than the full array element, as so:

[image: when availableTags='@Html.Raw(prereqs)']

Here's the code I'm using, which mostly comes from the JQueryUI demo.  The main line I've been playing with is `availableTags`.  (Note that `tutArray` is the desired array of strings and `prereqs = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(tutArray)`.  I've tried the following things:

`var availableTags = '@Html.Raw(prereqs)';` yields the above.

`var availableTags = '@prereqs';` yields the above, but the "'s are replaced with `&,q,u,o,t,;`.

`var availableTags = '@tutArray';` and `var availableTags = '@Html.Raw(tutArray)';` yield `S,y,s,t,e,m,.,S,t,r,i,n,g,[,]`.

```
@{
    var tutArray = tutList.ToArray();
    var prereqs = (new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(tutArray));
}
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {

        var availableTags = '@prereqs';

        function split(val) {
            return val.split(/,\s*/);
        }
        function extractLast(term) {
            return split(term).pop();
        }

        $("#prereqs")
            // don't navigate away from the field on tab when selecting an item
            .bind("keydown", function (event) {
                if (event.keyCode === $.ui.keyCode.TAB &&
                    $(this).data("ui-autocomplete").menu.active) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            })
            .autocomplete({
                minLength: 1,
                source: function (request, response) {
                    // delegate back to autocomplete, but extract the last term
                    response($.ui.autocomplete.filter(
                        availableTags, extractLast(request.term)));
                },
                focus: function () {
                    // prevent value inserted on focus
                    return false;
                },
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    var terms = split(this.value);
                    // remove the current input
                    terms.pop();
                    // add the selected item
                    terms.push(ui.item.value);
                    // add placeholder to get the comma-and-space at the end
                    terms.push("");
                    this.value = terms.join(", ");
                    return false;
                }
            });
    });
</script>

This should be an autocomplete box.
<p><input type="text" id="prereqs"/></p>
```

How can I get availableTags to parse the array as an array of strings (like [ "Inserting a Tag", "test1" ] etc)?

EDIT: For those that have been asking, here's the controller, though I don't think the problem is here.  This code is from PreReqs.cshtml, which is a very small part of the Tutorials/Edit page:

```
//
// GET: /Tutorials/Edit/5
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Edit(Int32 id)
{
    Tutorial tutorial = db.Tutorials.Find(id);
    ViewBag.Tutorials = (from tut in db.Tutorials
                             select tut).ToList();
    if (tutorial == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    ViewBag.CategoryId = new SelectList(db.Categories, "Id", "Name", tutorial.CategoryId);
    ViewBag.NextTutorialId = new SelectList(db.Tutorials, "Id", "Name", tutorial.NextTutorialId);
    return View(tutorial);
}
```

Comment: What do you see on this line when you view source?: 
`var availableTags = '@prereqs';`

Comment: Same as the above, except the `"` are replaced with `&quot;`, like this:  http://s24.postimg.org/u03thg0dh/prereqs.png

Comment: Whoop, I might have misunderstood.  Here's the page's source code: `var availableTags = '[&quot;Inserting a Tag&quot;,&quot;Test Tutorial 2&quot;,&quot;Test Tutorial 1&quot;,&quot;Test Tutorial w/ Pre-Reqs&quot;,&quot;ForEach Tag&quot;,&quot;Connecting to your SQL data&quot;,&quot;Connecting to your XML data&quot;,&quot;Accessing Sample Templates&quot;,&quot;Inserting Pre-Made Tags from the Data Bin&quot;,&quot;Out Tag - Formatting Dates and Currencies&quot;,&quot;Out Tag - Displaying Images&quot;]';`  This is the array, but it's a string for some reason?

Comment: Could you post the controller function?

Answer (score 0):

In your code you expect to have a JavaScript array assigned to `availableTags` variable. But because you enclosed the output in quotes, you're getting a string.
Remove quotes from this line:

```
var availableTags = '@prereqs';
```

Comment: When I use `var availableTags = @prereqs` (or, for that matter, `var availableTags = @Html.Raw(prereqs), the var seems to be set to the right thing (in the source code, it seems correct) but the autocomplete widget just doesn't work.  I can type things in the text box, but all autocomplete functionality is gone.  I also get a warning at compile about conditional compilation not being turned on.

Comment: Need more info on "just doesn't work". Conditions changed. Do you get any type of error? Can you see what's being sent to the server? Also, your controller action may not be working. Also, try `var availableTags = @(prereqs);`

Comment: For `@prereqs`, I get a warning when it compiles that 'conditional compilation is turned off'.  In the page's source code, `availableTags = ["Inserting a Tag","Test Tutorial 2"]` which is correct.  However, the box appears to be a normal text box, like so: http://s21.postimg.org/af0w8ahtj/tutarray.png  Using `@(prereqs)` hilights the `@` symbol with "Invalid character", but it still compiles and has the same behavior.  I'll post stuff about the controller in another comment since I'm out of space.

Comment: If it matters, currently the array is from ViewBag.Tutorials.ToArray() (my group collectively decided to use the ViewBag).  This code is for PreReqs.cshtml, which is a very small part of the Edit page for the Tutorials controller.  I don't think anything in the controller is causing the problem?